# Recebendo e Manipulando array com ajax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Boa noite, estou com uma duvida muito grande. E busco via ajax os tratamentos de um certo plano, e de acordo com cada tipo de especialidade ele tem que acrescentar um html. Pra ver melhor segue os códigos:

Ajax:

```
          function load_data_tratamentos()
      { 
        $.ajax({
          url:'<?=base_url()?>planos/getTratamentos',
          method:"get",
          dataType:"json",
          success:function(data)
          {
            if(data.tipo_especializacao == 'protese')
            {
              $('#protese_tratamentos').html(data.dados);
            }
            if(data.tipo_especializacao == 'ortodontia')
            {
              $('#ortodontia_tratamentos').html(data.dados);
            }  
            if(data.tipo_especializacao == 'implantodontia')
            {
              $('#implantodontia_tratamentos').html(data.dados);
            }
            if(data.tipo_especializacao == 'endodontia')
            {
              $('#endodontia_tratamentos').html(data.dados);
            }
            if(data.tipo_especializacao == 'clinica')
            {
              $('#clinica_tratamentos').html(data.dados);
            }              
          }
        });
      }
```

Controler:

```
public function getTratamentos()
{
    $query = $this->planos_model->getTratamentosByIdPlanos();
    echo json_encode($query);
}
```

Model:

```
public function getTratamentosByIdPlanos()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tratamentos');   
    $this->db->order_by('idTratamento', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $dados['dados'] = '';    
    $dados['tipo_especializacao'] = '';    
    $dados['id_plano'] = '';    

    if($query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {   
        foreach ($query->result() as $tratamento)
        { 

         $plano_usar = $tratamento->plano_usar == "S" ? "checked" : ""; 
         $dados['dados'] .= 
           '<div class="row">
           <input type="hidden" name="tipo_especializacao[]">
           <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3">
           <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
           <label class="bmd-label-floating">Tratamento</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="plano_tratamento[]" required="true" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" value="'.$tratamento->plano_tratamento.'">
           <input type="hidden" name"idTratamento" value="'.$tratamento->idTratamento.'">
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col mt-3">
           <div class="row" style="align-items: center;">
           <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
           <label class="bmd-label-floating">Valor</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="plano_tratamento_valor[]" required="true" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" value="'.$tratamento->plano_tratamento_valor.'">
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
           <div class="row justify-content-md-end text-right" style="align-items: center;">
           <div class="togglebutton">
           <label style="color: #000;">
           <input type="checkbox" name="plano_usar[]" '.$plano_usar.'>
           <span class="toggle"></span>
           Usar 
           </label>
           </div>
           <div class="div-actions" style="display: block; margin-left: 1em;">
           <a href="#" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-dark btn-link">
           <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 2em">delete</i>
           </a>                                                           
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>  
           </div>  
           </div>
           <hr class="hr-sansiq">                                            
           </div>';
            $dados['tipo_especializacao'] = $tratamento->tipo_especializacao;    
            $dados['id_plano'] = $tratamento->id_plano;
        }        
    }
    else
    {
        $dados['dados'] = '';    
        $dados['tipo_especializacao'] = '';    
        $dados['id_plano'] = ''; 
    }

    return $dados;

}
```

Como podem observar, dependendo do tipo de especialidade tem que ir pra uma div. Porém esta trazendo somente um tipo de especialidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$dados['tipo_especializacao'] = $tratamento->tipo_especializacao;`

esse valor é sobreescrito para cada item encontrado na base e por conta do 
`$this->db->order_by('idTratamento', 'ASC');` ele sempre terá o mesmo valor. Reveja essa estratégia de preenchimento.

Aproveitando, todo esse código

```
          {
            if(data.tipo_especializacao == 'protese')
            {
              $('#protese_tratamentos').html(data.dados);
            }
            if(data.tipo_especializacao == 'ortodontia')
            {
              $('#ortodontia_tratamentos').html(data.dados);
            }  
            if(data.tipo_especializacao == 'implantodontia')
            {
              $('#implantodontia_tratamentos').html(data.dados);
            }
            if(data.tipo_especializacao == 'endodontia')
            {
              $('#endodontia_tratamentos').html(data.dados);
            }
            if(data.tipo_especializacao == 'clinica')
            {
              $('#clinica_tratamentos').html(data.dados);
            }              
          }
```

poderia ser refatorado para algo como

```
success:function(data)
          { 
            $('#'+data.tipo_especializacao+'_tratamentos').html(data.dados);  
          }
```